# Column Type for XML Data in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, database-design, jpa

I'm using JPA with Hibernate and need to store smallish XML data(at most 500 characters) in the database.

I don't need to query XML data, that is, XML data will never be part of `WHERE` clauses.

What data type should I use for this?

Comment: Do you have a target database runtime? or is it meant to be generic, any database? is 500 chars a definite long term storage limit?

Comment: @John Ament I'm looking for a database agnostic solution and 500 is absolutely the maximum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a reason to use LOB here since 500 is your max length.  One option is to simply map a string to the column and parse the XML type externally.

Another option is to use the hibernate specific annotations to map external types - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2794

Answer (score 4):

Annotate your property with `@Lob` or use `type="clob"`.

> @Lob indicates that the property should be persisted in a Blob or a
>   Clob depending on the property type: java.sql.Clob, Character[],
>   char[] and java.lang.String will be persisted in a Clob.
>   java.sql.Blob, Byte[], byte[] and serializable type will be persisted
>   in a Blob.

[Source](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html) / [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96591/adl01int.htm)

You might also consider using lazy loading for this kind of data `@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`.

Answer (score 0):

XML is a text based format, and it is not a bad practice to store it in database, Microsoft SQL Server even has an XML data type. So, if you are using Microsoft SQL server you can use it. Please find more information on the below link from msdn:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403385.aspx
```

For, other databases as well, it is a good idea to store it in text format in varchar or nvarchar because in future if you want to query the database and process XML it would be very handy.